# AngularJS: preselect select element in ng-repeat based on other object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have a `ng-repeat` which `splits/filter` an email address into the single parts (name, domain before at and domain after at). In the repeater is a select for the domains. Now I want to preselect for each email address the domain.

```
<div ng-repeat="sender in email.Sender track by $index">
<!-- other html -->
<select class="form-control" 
        ng-model="displayDomain" 
        ng-options="senderDomain.Domain as senderDomain.Domain for senderDomain in senderDomains"
        ng-init="displayDomain = sender.Name | splitSenderData:'domain.afterAt'">
</select>
</div>
```

My try was with the `ng-init` and a `filter` based value but that dont work.

Comment: Could you please clearly explain your requirement and post post you controller code also. Even Fiddle is appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ng-selected

```
ng-selected="{{displayDomain == sender.Name}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my code from string and filter to an more complex object because so I can read and save the data more easily (for an angular beginner).